# Wordpress : Buttons for isotope transition does nothing

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, woocommerce, jquery-isotope

I'm trying to make a dynamic galery of products with categories using Isotope and Woocommerce on wordpress but I'm stuck because the buttons don't do anything when I click on them and the console shows no error and I can't figure out why it doesn't work.

I'm using wordpress 5.2.2 with an ark theme ,bootstrap v4 and jquery version 2.2.4 . I've tried using diferent jquery versions , I've also tried to redo everything in a  clean and local wordpress instalation but I had some Animsition errors .

Here is how a build the gallery in php:

```php
function gallery(){

    Print "<div class='button-group filter-button-group'>
            <button data-filter='*' >show all</button>
            <button data-filter='.music-album'>Music</button>
            <button data-filter='.movie-soundtrack'>Movies</button>
            <button data-filter='.game-soundtrack'>Games</button>
            </div>";
    Print"<div class='row'>";

    $articles = new WP_Query(['post_type'=>'product']);

    if($articles->have_posts()) : while ($articles->have_posts()) : $articles->the_post();

        $product_cats = wp_get_post_terms( get_the_ID(), 'product_cat' );
        $single_cat = array_shift( $product_cats );
        $category = $single_cat->slug.' ';

        Print"<a class='grid-item ".$category."' href='".get_the_permalink()."'>";
        Print"<div class='card grid-item".$category."'>";
            Print"<img class='card-img-top'src='".get_field('image')."'alt='' width='200' height='200'>";
            Print"<h1 class='card-body'>"; the_title(); Print"</h1>";
        Print"</div>";
        Print"</a>";


    endwhile;endif; 

    Print"</div>";

}
```

And here is the javascript :

```
jQuery.noConflict();

var $grid = jQuery('.grid').isotope({
  // options
  itemSelector: '.grid-item',
  layoutMode: 'fitRows'
});



jQuery('.filter-button-group').on('click', 'button', function() {
  var filterValue = jQuery(this).attr('data-filter');
  console.log(filterValue); // for tests
  $grid.isotope({ filter: filterValue });
});
```

The buttons should sort the products by category with transitions but when I click it doesn't sort anything at all and the console doesn't return any Error .

Comment: You should wrap the whole thing with `grid` class `div`. You are using isotope of `.grid` class and there is no grid in your code.

Comment: @Manjunath Well that was it , I'm kinda ashamed ... Thank you a lot !

Comment: Nothing to be ashamed of. We all have been there :P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Manjunath said my "items" were not part of the grid I wanted to sort. So I just had to add "grid" to the class of my galery div .

Thank You Manjunath !